# JQuery Ajax Tagit Array to PHP returning [object Object]

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, arrays

I've tried to implement Tagit to my website, but I can't get the array of tags to behave in a way I want it to...

I've googled and tried a bunch of different things but cant get it to work.

This is my JavaScript function:

```
function saveSkillTags( tags ) {
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  dataType: "json",
traditional: true,
  url: "/../includes/ajaxController.php",
  data: {actionCommand : "SAVE_SKILL_TAGS", tags : tags }
}).done(function( res ) {
    console.debug('klar');
});
}
```

Console.debug showed me that the "tags" array looks like this:

```
[Object { label="php",  value="php",  element=[1],  mer...}, Object { label="ajax",  value="ajax",  element=[1],  mer...}, Object { label="javascript",  value="javascript",  element=[1],  mer...}, Object { label="jquery",  value="jquery",  element=[1],  mer...}]
```

It posts to my ajaxController which has this code:

```
if( $actionCommand == 'SAVE_SKILL_TAGS' ) {
require_once( dirname( __FILE__ ).'/../classes/stuff.class.php' );
$list = new UserStuff();
$list->saveSkillTags( $utility->getUserId(), $_POST['tags'] );
}
```

So, so far so good...

Then in stuff.class.php I have the function "saveSkillTags". Here is the problem...
I've tried to encode and decode json, and tried it just without json, but I can't get anything to work...
Here is the function:

```
function saveSkillTags( $userId, $tags ) {
    $dbCon = new DBConnection();
    //$tags = json_decode($tags);
    error_log($tags);
    foreach ( $tags as $tag => $value ) {
        $skillTag = $dbCon->escape( $value );
        $query = "INSERT INTO skilltag SET ";
        $query .= "User_fk=".$userId;
        $query .= ", TagName='".$skillTag."'";
        $dbCon->execute( $query );
        error_log($query);
    }
    
    mysql_close();
    echo 'true';
}
```

As you see, I error_log $tags.

And when I run this setup I get two errors. The first one is the $tags var, and the second one is generated.

```
[24-Aug-2012 22:28:35] [object Object]

[24-Aug-2012 22:28:35] PHP Warning:  Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in C:\Users\...\classes\stuff.class.php on line 103
```

I've fiddled with this now for several hours and starting to doubt my programming skills heavily...

Please help me get back on track, even a hint would be much appreciated!

Comment: Try re-instating the `json_decode` and doing a `var_dump` instead of `error_log` so you can see the data structure.

Comment: As soon as i re-instating the `json_decode` it shows nothing instead of `[object Object]`...

Comment: OK, what is the `var_dump` of `$tags` without `json_decode`? It will be shown on the page, not the error log.

Comment: The response is `"[{"label":"kaljsd","value":"kaljsd","element":{"0":{},"length":1},"index":0},{"label":"laksjd","value":"laksjd","element":{"0":{},"length":1},"index":1},{"label":"lkajdasd","value":"lkajdasd","element":{"0":{},"length":1},"index":2}]"` But this is with @Raidenace tip with the `JSON.stringify(tags)`.
Now i just somehow got to parse it through a for-loop wich im not an expert in...

Comment: Just `json_decode` that Json and you'll be fine with the `foreach`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need to do is pass the data inside `tags` as JSON - currently it is being posted a object. In order to do this use `JSON.stringify()`

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  dataType: "json",
traditional: true,
  url: "test.php",
  data: {actionCommand : "SAVE_SKILL_TAGS", tags : JSON.stringify(tags) }
}).done(function( res ) {
    alert(res);
});
});
```

`JSON.stringify` is available in most modern browsers (but maybe not in some older ones). Basically it takes a Javascript object and converts it into a JSON string. Note that when stringifying, it might escape quotes and stuff, to ensure that the resultant JSON is valid.

So in the PHP script, if you do a `print_r($_POST['tags'])`, you should see how the JSON looks and then you can adjust your code accordingly.

**UPDATE**

Try the following foreach loop:

```
foreach ( $tags as $tag => $value ) 
{ 
    $skillTag = $value->value; 
    $query = "INSERT INTO skilltag (User_fk, TagName) values ('".$userId."','".$skillTag."')"; 
    $dbCon->execute( $query ); 
}
```

Comment: That gets me the json! Sweet! Now i just have too loop it through a for loop, but i will try that! Thanks so far!

Comment: Have updated some code to help you convert the string to PHP Object Array which will make it easier to loop through it

Comment: Thank you so much man for all your help!
But when i loop it like this:
`foreach ( $tags as $tag => $value ) {
   $skillTag = $value;
    //$skillTag = $dbCon->escape( $value );
   $query = "INSERT INTO skilltag SET ";
   $query .= "User_fk=".$userId;
   $query .= ", TagName='".$skillTag."'";
   $dbCon->execute( $query );
  }`
I get this error:
`[25-Aug-2012 01:04:08] PHP Catchable fatal error:  Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string in C:\Users\...\stuff.class.php on line 109`
I cant figure out how to loop it so it gets the value and i've tried alot. Thanks so much again!

Comment: `I get this error: [25-Aug-2012 01:04:08] PHP Catchable fatal error: Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string in C:\Users\...\stuff.class.php on line 109` *

Comment: Can you do a `print_r($tags);` (before the for loop) and paste the output so that I can see what you are looping through?

Comment: I've got this: `Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [label] => php
            [value] => php
            [element] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [0] => stdClass Object
                        (
                        )

                    [length] => 1
                )

            [index] => 0
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [label] => ajax
            [value] => ajax
            [element] => stdClass Object
                (.........

)`

Comment: Ok, your looping is definitely wrong. What content do you want stored in `TagName` field for each record? is it `label` or `value`?

Comment: Yeah, i kind of figured, but i cant see how to fix it. I cant grasp multidimensional arrays. I want to store the `value`, they are the same but the `value` is what i want to store. I appreciate your help very much btw.

Comment: I have updated the answer with an edited foreach loop, which I think will work for you in looping through the array and storing value. Btw, your SQL syntax was wrong, I have updated that as well. Run that foreach and see if that helps.

Comment: Oh my, it works! And the best thing is, I get why! I see what i did wrong and why this is right. Thank you so much man, Im very greateful and thanks for your time and patience!